# How to show errors/warnings by hotkey in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have to show errors/warnings by mouse now. Is there any hotkey or special button? I could find nothing in "Keyboard Shortcuts". Example of error:

[image]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The corresponding cmd name in VS Keybindings is `editor.action.showHover`. On mac for me the key combo was: `cmd+k cmd+i`. I'm not sure what it is on windows but you can find out through your **command palette** by typing `show hover`. It will show you the current keybinding and you can execute it as well.

If you would like [you can remap it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) like this:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "editor.action.showHover",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

With that, if your cursor is within an error/warning squiggly line, you can hit `ctrl+e` to show what you would normally see with hover.

To make the box disappear, hit escape.

Comment: On Windows `ctrl+k ctrl+i` shows the hover.

Comment: As it is mentioned in the shortcuts cheat sheet (Help - Keyboard Shortcuts Reference) on Linux on default the same is  `ctrl` + `k` `ctrl` + `i`.

Comment: For whatever reason this doesn't show info about the error that your cursor is over, just info about the method.

Comment: +1 for explicitly providing the name of the command which is the only portable information for all platforms. Finding the, maybe even rebound, key-binding from there is always possible with Alt-X (:lol:, which I bound to "show all commands" ages ago and would have to look up here to find the default: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

Answer (score 61):

In case you are using VSCode in vim mode (VSCodeVim extension) move your cursor to the underlined code and type `gh`.

See https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#-vscodevim-tricks

Answer (score 27):

Pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> will focus the next problem/error. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> will focus the previous problem. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) you can find an overview of all shortcuts for windows.

Comment: I found it. But it is not comfrotable when you have many warnings. For example, I use spell checker, and it marks some names of packages as mistake.

Answer (score 2):

On mac you can use

```
cmd+k cmd+i
```

it shows [image]

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+k, n` will show you the under carret error as inline text
(the same way that `F8` / `shift + F8` does)
rather than a hovering tooltip as `ctrl+k, ctrl+i` does.